# \openright command does not work properly

Tags: thesis, double-sided, book-class

I am writing my Doctorate thesis in Latex. I am using book class, which by default is twoside and openright. But for the preliminary pages, specifically for page number ii, certificate, it needs to be printed on a new page, but the result is coming out as a larger right-side margin page for being an even-numbered page. The same problem arises for the list of figures and tables also, they are also starting on an even page and the output is a bigger right margin.
Please help to overcome the situation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey user48317. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your current setup? We need to be able to see that as there are many things at play that could influence the possible solutions. Your minimal example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. You don't have to include personal details... just something that replicates the setup that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see what you're seeing.

Comment: large right margin is expected for an odd, right hand page. margins are space for your thumbs on the outside edge